# Flutter - Audio Recording - How to achieve the sin wave form according to frequency when a user hits the record button?

Tags: audio, flutter, dart, trigonometry, wave

I want to achieve this look when the user starts recording his voice, the wave act accordingly to the frequencies.
How to achieve this using flutter? what's the concept?

[Sin frequency wave example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP4TM.png)

Comment: have you get any solution?